# Работа декоратора callback_query_handlers в telebot

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой, при использовании библиотеки telebot, для написания бота в telegram.

Есть две функции, которые очень похожи друг на друга, я сделаю их "условными", для простоты понимания вопроса

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=["First"])
def set_system_first(message):
    Какой-то код, предоставляющий выбор пользователю. Кнопки.

@bot.callback_query_handlers(func=lambda call: True)    # Обработчик
def callback_inline_first(message):
    А код вот тут "ловит" выбор пользователя на "кнопках"
```

Вроде всё просто, и ничего особенного нет, но дальше, идут почти точно такие же функции:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=["Second"])
def set_system_second(message):
    Какой-то код, предоставляющий выбор пользователю. Кнопки.

@bot.callback_query_handlers(func=lambda call: True)    # Обработчик
def callback_inline_second(message):
    А код вот тут "ловит" выбор пользователя на "кнопках"
```

И вот тут у меня возникла сложность:

Когда я вызываю, например первую функцию (First), - далее отлавливаю выбор пользователя, все хорошо. Но как только, мне нужно перейти к функции Second - декоратор и функция

```
@bot.callback_query_handlers(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_inline_first(message):
```

так и остаётся работать (тот самый, что под первой функцией).

Таким образом, никак не получается условно говоря "закончить" работу первого декоратора/функции, и перейти ко "второму".

Пробовал и вкладывать функцию "обработчик" в основную функцию,

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=["First"])
def set_system_first(message):
    Какой-то код, предоставляющий выбор пользователю. Кнопки.

    @bot.callback_query_handlers(func=lambda call: True)    # Обработчик
    def callback_inline_first(message):
        А код вот тут "ловит" выбор пользователя на "кнопках"
```

Все равно - не получается. Первая функция обработчик - всегда "сторожит" и обрабатывает ответ от функции Second.

Прошу Вашей помощи, быть может кто-то работал с библиотекой telebot

---

В моем случае, пользователю предоставляется выбор из 20 до 50 кнопок в первом случае (First), и столько же кнопок во втором случае (Second). В обработчиках я получаю переменную выбора, т.е. например при вызове функции First - пользователь выбрал число 20 - я его запоминаю, и далее с ним работаю. Ожидается, что потом пользователь выберет некое другое число при вызове функции Second, я так же его получу. И далее зная две эти переменные, я уже вывожу человеку определенный результат.

Т.е. мне не нужен принцип "ветвления" в данных фунциях, типа

```
если пользователь выбрал А:
   делай то
если пользователь выбрал Б:
   делай сё
```

мне в обработчике нужно "просто" узнать, что пользователь выбрал при исполнении первой функции [First], и что выбрал пользователь при исполнении второй функции [Second]

Answer (score 1):

По идее, как-то так должно работать:

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data == 'Кнопка1')
def callback_inline_first(message):
    # Какой-то код

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data == 'Кнопка2')
def callback_inline_second(message):
    # Какой-то код
```

Только вместо "Кнопка1" и "Кнопка2" подставляете строки, соответствующие вашим кнопкам.

Comment: Да, про реализацию такого метода, я знаю.

Однако в моем случае, пользователю предоставляется выбор из 20 до 50 кнопок в первом случае (First), и столько же кнопок во втором случае(Second). 

В обработчиках я получаю переменную выбора, т.е. например при вызове функции First - пользователь выбрал число 20 - я его запоминаю, и далее с ним работаю.

Ожидается, что потом пользователь выберет некое другое число при вызове функции Second, я так же его получу.

И далее зная две эти переменные, я уже вывожу человеку определенный результат.

Comment: Т.е. мне не нужен принцип "ветвления" в данных фунциях, типа "если пользователь выбрал кнопку 1, то..., если два то...и т.д.", мне в обработчике нужно просто узнать, что пользователь выбрал при исполнении первой функции [First], и что выбрал пользователь при исполнении второй функции [Second]

Answer (score 1):

с сайта: https://habr.com/ru/post/442800/
Там описывается метод позволяющий переключать handler

"Допустим, теперь наш бот будет спрашивать у пользователя по очереди его имя, фамилию и возраст. Для этого мы будем использовать метод "register_next_step_handler" бота:"

```
name = '';
surname = '';
age = 0;
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def start(message):
    if message.text == '/reg':
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Как тебя зовут?");
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, get_name); #следующий шаг – функция get_name
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Напиши /reg');

def get_name(message): #получаем фамилию
    global name;
    name = message.text;
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Какая у тебя фамилия?');
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, get_surnme);

def get_surname(message):
    global surname;
    surname = message.text;
    bot.send_message('Сколько тебе лет?');
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, get_age);
```